# Sort array by numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

How can I sort this array by array keys?

```
array(
4 => 'four',
3 => 'three',
2 => 'two',
1 => 'one',
)
```

Desired result:

```
array(
1 => 'one',
2 => 'two',
3 => 'three',
4 => 'four',
)
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted ... extract the keys into a separate list and sort that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you just want to reverse the order, use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse):

```
$reverse = array_reverse($array, true);
```

The second parameter is for preserving the keys.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to sort the keys in DESC order use:

```
krsort($arr);
```

If you want to sort the values in DESC order and maintain index association use:

```
arsort($arr);
```

If you want to sort the values in DESC natural order and maintain index association use:

```
natcasesort($arr);
$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an array, you want to sort it by keys, in reverse order -- you can use the [`krsort`](http://php.net/krsort) function :

> Sorts an array by key in reverse
>   order, maintaining key to data
>   correlations. This is useful mainly
>   for associative arrays.

In you case, you'd have this kind of code :

```
$arr = array(
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'three',
    4 => 'four',
);

krsort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

which would get you this kind of output :

```
$ /usr/local/php-5.3/bin/php temp.php
array(4) {
  [4]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
}
```

As a sidenode : if you had wanted to sort by values, you could have used [`arsort`](http://php.net/arsort) -- but it doesn't seem to be what you want, here.

Answer (score 0):

Try [krsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) - that will sort in reverse using the array key, whereas rsort will sort on the array value.